# PEG grammar ordered choice failure

Tags: python, parsing, peg, arpeggio

I have a PEG grammar for a toy DSL using the Python [Arpeggio](https://github.com/textX/Arpeggio/blob/master/docs/grammars.md) package:

```py
from arpeggio.cleanpeg import ParserPEG

grammar = """
    root    = block* EOF
    block   = header (item1+ / item2+)
    header  = "block"
    item1   = number name comment?
    item2   = number name list comment?
    number  = r"\d+"
    name    = r"\w+"
    list    = r"\[.*\]"
    comment = r"\/\/.*"
"""

doc = """
block
  5 alpha []        //
  3 beta [a, b, c]  // this is an item2

block
  6 foo
  1 bar  // This is an item1
  4 baz  // more stuff
"""

parser = ParserPEG(grammar, 'root', debug=True)
parse_tree = parser.parse(doc)
print ('Tree:', parse_tree)
```

This gives strange results when parsing the test document: it correctly fails to match `item1` in the ordered choice, but then falsely claims (the line marked with `xxxx`) that it did match the choice without ever testing `item2`, which would have matched.

```
>> Matching rule root=Sequence at position 0 => * block   5
   >> Matching rule ZeroOrMore in root at position 0 => * block   5
      >> Matching rule block=Sequence in root at position 0 => * block   5
         ?? Try match rule header=StrMatch(block) in block at position 1 =>  *block   5 
         ++ Match 'block' at 1 => ' *block*   5 '
         >> Matching rule OrderedChoice in block at position 6 =>  block*   5 alpha
            >> Matching rule OneOrMore in block at position 6 =>  block*   5 alpha
               >> Matching rule item1=Sequence in block at position 6 =>  block*   5 alpha
                  ?? Try match rule number=RegExMatch(\d+) in item1 at position 9 =>  block   *5 alpha []
                  ++ Match '5' at 9 => ' block   *5* alpha []'
                  ?? Try match rule name=RegExMatch(\w+) in item1 at position 11 => block   5 *alpha []  
                  ++ Match 'alpha' at 11 => 'block   5 *alpha* []  '
                  >> Matching rule Optional in item1 at position 16 =>    5 alpha* []       
                     ?? Try match rule comment=RegExMatch(\/\/.*) in item1 at position 17 =>   5 alpha *[]        
                     -- NoMatch at 17
                  <<- Not matched rule Optional in item1 at position 16 =>    5 alpha* []       
               <<+ Matched rule item1=Sequence in item1 at position 16 =>    5 alpha* []       
               >> Matching rule item1=Sequence in block at position 16 =>    5 alpha* []       
                  ?? Try match rule number=RegExMatch(\d+) in item1 at position 17 =>   5 alpha *[]        
                  -- NoMatch at 17
               <<- Not matched rule item1=Sequence in item1 at position 16 =>    5 alpha* []
xxxx-->     <<+ Matched rule OneOrMore in block at position 16 =>    5 alpha* []       
         <<+ Matched rule OrderedChoice in block at position 16 =>    5 alpha* []       
      <<+ Matched rule block=Sequence in block at position 16 =>    5 alpha* []       
      >> Matching rule block=Sequence in root at position 16 =>    5 alpha* []       
         ?? Try match rule header=StrMatch(block) in block at position 17 =>   5 alpha *[]        
         -- No match 'block' at 17 => '  5 alpha *[]   *     '
      <<- Not matched rule block=Sequence in block at position 16 =>    5 alpha* []       
   <<+ Matched rule ZeroOrMore in root at position 16 =>    5 alpha* []       
   ?? Try match rule EOF in root at position 17 =>   5 alpha *[]        
   !! EOF not matched.
<<- Not matched rule root=Sequence in root at position 0 => * block   5
```

As a result, the parser failed to consume the `item2`s that it would have consumed had it actually matched `item2` after `item1` failed.

**Is this a bug in the parser package, or in my grammar?**

Note that reversing the ordered choice:

```
    block   = header (item2+ / item1+)
```

correctly parses the example document.  But an anomalous result that is easy to work around in a toy problem may be much more difficult to find in real grammars.  An item is unambiguously either an item1 or item2, so the order in which they are checked should be irrelevant, and the code for parsing them should work consistently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [PEG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing_expression_grammar) the order of expressions is `OrderedChoice` is important. When the parser try `item1+` it is enough to match at least one of `item1` to succeed and the whole ordered choice is then considered successful.

In general, always put more specific matches at the beginning and more general towards the end of ordered choice.

Update: there is a nice explanation in [Ambiguity detection and influence of rule order on language that is matched](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parsing_expression_grammar#Ambiguity_detection_and_influence_of_rule_order_on_language_that_is_matched) section on Wikipedia.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation.  And for the package - it's debugging feature is fantastic!  As a grammar novice, I'm wondering if seeing errors like "shift/reduce conflict" might be more helpful than using a grammar that is always unambiguous but sometimes counter-intuitive.   Are there any "PEG Lint" tools that flag instances where an ordered choice would become ambiguous if it were unordered?

Comment: @dave: your grammar does not have a shift-reduce conflict and a LALR parser generator would produce a parser which would work as expected. (Tried with Sly.)

Comment: I didn't mean a specific error.  I observed that the PEG behaved in an unexpected way, which the Wikipedia link confirmed: "... may be arbitrary and lead to surprising parses."  If tooling could detect instances where "the ordering of productions" in a grammar "affects the language matched", it would be helpful to flag those cases for special scrutiny.   In other words, reordering some ordered choices might not have any effect, but for others it obviously does.

Comment: @Dave: I think that practically all non-trivial PEG grammars would trigger a tool which detected cases where ordered choice makes a difference, because it is a key feature of PEG. But I don't use PEG (precisely because of this aspect) so I could well be projecting from a prejudice.

Comment: I'm not aware of any tool that could do such check. I even think that I read somewhere that the problem is proven to be undecidable. @rici Agreed, PEGs are not very helpful from the analysis point of view, with shift/reduce parsing you get at least some clue if you have ambiguity or need more lookahead at some point.

Comment: My goal is first maximum readability of the grammar for use in documentation, and second.a minimum-footprint parser for embedded applications.   PEGs look promising for that application, but I may have to investigate other approaches.

Answer (score 2):

It's a bug in your grammar, I'm afraid.

`item1` is a number, a word and an optional comment. `5 alpha` fits that description, so it is a successful match. `item1+` matches one or more `item1`s and there was one `item1`, so that's all good; it has found a `block`.

The goal was `block* EOF`, i.e. "zero or more `block` followed by an end of file indicator. And it has found a `block`, but that `block` is not followed by another `block` nor by an EOF. (It's followed by a list.) So now the parser has run out of choices, so it declares failure.

PEG parsers do not retry successful parses; that's the key aspect to PEG parsing. Once a subexpression matches, PEG will not trade it for a different subexpression.